# Is visible in viewport is returning visible for everything on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, visibility, viewport

Can anyone offer me some advice? I have the following code to detect when items are in the viewport, unfortunately the first .each loop (which isn't triggered by scrolling) returns visible for every item, why is this?

```
window.onload = function(){

  $.fn.visible = function(detectPartial){
    detectPartial = (!!detectPartial); // if null or undefined, default to false

    var viewport = $(window),
        vpWidth = viewport.width(),
        vpHeight = viewport.height(),
        vpTop = viewport.scrollTop(),
        vpBottom = vpTop + vpHeight,
        vpLeft = viewport.scrollLeft(),
        vpRight = vpLeft + vpWidth,

        elementOffset = $(this).offset(),
        elementTopArea = elementOffset.top+((detectPartial) ? $(this).height() : 0),
        elementBottomArea = elementOffset.top+((detectPartial) ? 0 : $(this).height()),
        elementLeftArea = elementOffset.left+((detectPartial) ? $(this).width() : 0),
        elementRightArea = elementOffset.left+((detectPartial) ? 0 : $(this).width());

       return ((elementBottomArea <= vpBottom) && (elementTopArea >= vpTop)) && ((elementRightArea <= vpRight) && (elementLeftArea >= vpLeft));
  }

  $('.portfolio-image-box').each(function(i, el){
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      el.addClass("in")
    } else{
      el.addClass("out")
    }
  })

  $(document).scroll(function() {
    $('.portfolio-image-box').each(function(i, el){
        var el = $(el);
        if (el.visible(true)) {
          el.removeClass("out")
          el.addClass("in")
        } else{
          el.removeClass("in")
          el.addClass("out")
        }
    })
  })

}
```

Comment: Can you give us a bit of HTML or fiddle for us to test the code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dancinwolfe/7fydgdL3/4/ I think that's correct, had to mess with the html and css a tiny bit as I was using laravel and bootstrap.

Comment: Going for lunch right now, but just a quick head up for the fiddle, don't put the windows.onload since its already inside a window.onload. Also include Jquery in the library by clicking on the top right corner of the js code

Comment: What are `in` and `out` class for? are they meant for show/hide?

Comment: That's just for testing purposes, in is visible out is not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I modified your code slightly and did a check in the console to see if the classes are getting added and removed, and it worked. Try the below code and check in the firebug, as you scroll, classes gets added and removed for whatever in there in the viewport:

```js
$.fn.visible = function(detectPartial) {
  detectPartial = (!!detectPartial); // if null or undefined, default to false

  var viewport = $(window),
    vpWidth = viewport.width(),
    vpHeight = viewport.height(),
    vpTop = viewport.scrollTop() + $('#navbar').outerHeight(),
    vpBottom = vpTop + vpHeight,
    vpLeft = viewport.scrollLeft(),
    vpRight = vpLeft + vpWidth,

    elementOffset = $(this).offset(),
    elementTopArea = elementOffset.top + ((detectPartial) ? $(this).height() : 0),
    elementBottomArea = elementOffset.top + ((detectPartial) ? 0 : $(this).height()),
    elementLeftArea = elementOffset.left + ((detectPartial) ? $(this).width() : 0),
    elementRightArea = elementOffset.left + ((detectPartial) ? 0 : $(this).width());

  return ((elementBottomArea <= vpBottom) && (elementTopArea >= vpTop)) && ((elementRightArea <= vpRight) && (elementLeftArea >= vpLeft));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  addInAndOut();
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    addInAndOut();
  });
});


function addInAndOut() {
  $('.portfolio-image-box').each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      el.removeClass("out").addClass("in");
    } else {
      el.removeClass("in").addClass("out");
    }
  })
}
```

```css
#navbar {
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 1.5vh;
  padding: 1.5vh;
}

#navbar .fa {
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-top: 6vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.portfolio-image-box {
  height: 25%;
  width: 14.66vw;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 0.5vh;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio-image-box:hover {
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

#portfolio {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

#portfolio-container {
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}

.portfolio-image {
  height: 100%;
}

#body-title {
  color: #c84630;
}

.col-md-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <h1 id="body-title" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">Portfolio</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 portfolio">
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-image-box col-md-12">
    <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just tried this out using chrome developer tools and it's still marking every image as in by default, then only changing them to out after i've scrolled and they've entered and left the viewport.

Comment: I clicked on 'Run code snippet' and can see only one 'in' while rest all are marked as 'out'. On scrolling, it marks new incoming ones as 'in' while previous ones as 'out'. I am running on Chrome too.

Comment: I've just checked the snipped and it works, but when I copy your answer into the site I'm developing I'm still left with the same problem?

Comment: May be some other code is or might be conflicting with it. If you share end-result / rendered HTML and JS, may be we can check and help you out.

Comment: I have tried removing all other dependencies other than the JS file in question, it has no affect. Could it be something to do with the way Laravel loads images/views?

Comment: Might be. Not sure. May be you can clear cache with `php artisan cache:clear` to see if it reflects. Can't think of anything else :(

Comment: Tried it, I'm giving up on this cause I can't find a solution and it's just a superficial feature. Technically you solved the issue so you can have the 50 rep :P